# Webservice for mobile Application using REST Service in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, rest, restful-architecture

I have to create a webservice for mobile application(IPhone and Android) in Rest Service. This Application is based one E-Publishing. I try some REST service based on SLIM . I can able to add a data into db and also retrieve the data from DB.

I use the following link to develop REST Service

```
http://phpmaster.com/writing-a-restful-web-service-with-slim/
```

I am able to add a new data through form in html but i want to use url to add a data. but i cant. here is the code i used

```
<form action="http://localhost/samples/Restfull/samp5/index.php/custom" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="POST">
 Name: <input type="text" name="Customer_Name"><br>
 Mobile: <input type="text" name="Customer_Mobile"><br>
 Email: <input type="text" name="Customer_Email"><br>
 Address: <textarea name="Customer_Address"></textarea>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When i try through this form , the operation is successfully done. But i want to make that as web service. I try to add data through url but failed, at the same time Delete or get data by using join queries also not working.

I retrieve data from Db by using following function

```
$app->get("/custom/:id", function ($id) use ($app, $db) {
    $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    $custom = $db->Registration()->where("Registration_Id", $id);
    if ($data = $custom->fetch()) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "custom_Name" => $data["Customer_Name"],
            "custom_Mobile" => $data["Customer_Mobile"],
            "custom_Email" => $data["Customer_Email"],
            "custom_Address" => $data["Customer_Address"]
            ));
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(array(
            "status" => false,
            "message" => " $id does not exist"
            ));
    }
});
```

This also works well.

Is any other way or good samples available. Not only in Slim. I need to integrate REST Service. Please suggest on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly did you mean by "I  am able to add a new data through form in html but i want to use url to add a data" ? do you want to develop rest service which takes values with url ?

Comment: S i want to develop rest service which takes values with url

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this is where you need to get started :)

If you are going to use the url to set data then you are have to use HTTP get method. If you use java to develop the restful service I suggest you to use [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) (JAX-RS (JSR 311) Reference Implementation for building RESTful Web services.)

At your project service you can define methods with HTTP get method

```
@Stateless
@Path("/basepath")
@javax.ws.rs.Produces("application/json")
@javax.ws.rs.Consume("application/json")
public class RestService {

    @Path("/{index}")
    public String M(@PathParam("index") String index){
      //you can use index value here

    }

}
```

so what ever after the "basepath/" in your URL, you can use that value.

If you want to get started with restful services, it is very easy to do with Netbeans.
here are some links that might help you.

[netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)
[netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/intro-ws.html](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/intro-ws.html)

Comment: Thanks RJ45 . i think it is based on Java.. I need purely for PHP. Is possible to use this in PHP?

Comment: Restful is a architecture, so it is not dependent on a programing language.But it is difficult to find good example on php. Also as mentioned here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) if we can develop the service to relevant criteria it is a restful service.